# Understanding the Need for \null After \hfill in LaTeX Figure Environment

Tags: floats

Hello TeX Stack Exchange,

I am working on a document using the `figure` environment and have encountered a layout issue related to the `\hfill` command. My aim is to evenly distribute two `tikzpicture` environments within the figure. I've noticed that to achieve the desired spacing, I need to include a `\null` command after the last `\hfill`. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```latex
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \hfill
    % First tikzpicture environment
    \begin{tikzpicture}[...]
        % TikZ commands
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hfill
    % Second tikzpicture environment
    \begin{tikzpicture}[...]
        % TikZ commands
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hfill\null
    \caption{Prohibited lines}
\end{figure}
```

My question is: Why is the `\null` command necessary after the third `\hfill` for the horizontal space to be distributed correctly? Without `\null`, the spacing does not work as expected. There is no space on the right of the second tikz picture. Could you please help me understand the underlying mechanics of `\hfill` and `\null` in this context?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: `\caption` starts and ends with a `\par`.  A better solution is to use `\hfil` btween the two tikzpictures and let `\centering` handle the edges.

Comment: Addendum to John's comment: space or glue at the end of a paragraph is ignored. But with `\null` the infinite glue is not at the very end of the paragraph. Instead an empty `\hbox{}` is at the end after the infinite glue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer present here 5 hours ago shows that you don't need `\hfill` because `\centering` inserts `\hfil` on the left and right sides. But it doesn't include the answer to your question about why you need to insert `\null` in your code if `\hfill` is used. Yes the usage of `\hfill` suppresses the implicit `\hfil` (inserted from `\leftskip`, `\rightskip` TeX primitive registers when the `\centering` macro is used), so we have to see where the `\hfill`s are and (more important) where they remain when the paragraph is processed.

TeX removes the last glue (i.e. `\hfill` in this example) when `\par` is invoked in horizontal mode. You entered horizontal mode by the first `\hfill`, then the first image, then the second `\hfill`, then the second image, then the last `\hfill` are inserted. All this material is included in a horizontal list. Then the `\caption` macro runs `\par` before it starts its own printing. And this `\par` removes the last glue from the horizontal list, i.e. the last `\hfill`. And it creates a one-line paragraph: `\hfill`, image, `\hfill`, image.

On the other hand, if there is `\null` here (i.e. `\hbox{}`) then the horizontal list includes `\hfill`, image, `\hfill`, image, `\hfill`, `\hbox{}`. Now, the last item in this horizontal list isn't glue, so nothing is removed by the following `\par`.

I recommend using `\hbox to\hsize` (i.e. `\centerline` from plain TeX) instead of LaTeX's `\centering` macro. ​You are in control of what box is created:

```
\hbox to\hsize{%
   \hfil
   first image
   \hfil
   second image
   \hfil
}
```

Of course, you can replace all occurrences of `\hfil` by `\hfill` in this code and nothing is changed.

Comment: My answer contains the detail about `\null`, namely that it should *never* be used in a LaTeX `document` environment. See also the fina suggestion about `\hspace*` (which you probably know as `\hglue`).

Answer (score 3):

You *don't* need `\null`. Ever.

Under the scope of `\centering`, LaTeX adds `\hfil` glue at either side, so what you need is just `\hfil` between the figures.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering

%%%% this is just for showing the spaces are equal
\rule{\dimeval{(\textwidth-8cm)/3}}{0.4pt}\hfill
\rule{\dimeval{(\textwidth-8cm)/3}}{0.4pt}\hfill
\rule{\dimeval{(\textwidth-8cm)/3}}{0.4pt}
\bigskip
%%%%

\framebox[4cm]{\rule{0pt}{3cm}}% <--- 
\hfil
\framebox[4cm]{\rule{0pt}{3cm}}

\caption{Prohibited lines}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, if you want horizontal space that's not gobbled at a line break, use `\hspace*`. In your case `\hspace*{\fill}` would do, but, as you see above, the solution is simpler.