# Align the tops of two minipages

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I would like to align the tops of two minipages.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
    What do you think of this situation?

    \vspace{1cm}
    \begin{center}
    \underline{\hspace{0.75\textwidth}}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
\end{document}
```

Here is the output I get using `pdflatex`:

[image]

I would like the "What do you think of this situation?" text to be at the top. Is there a way to do it? I would like to avoid explicitly setting the height of the minipages since the `lipsum` text could change later.

Comment: Use `\begin{minipage}[t]{<width>}` on both your `minipage`s.

Comment: That doesn't do it in this case. It seems `tcolorbox` causes an issue unless we add `box align=top`.

Comment: Another trick is to add `\hrule height0pt` as the first line in each minipage.  Technically, [t] aligns the baseline of the first line, which in this case would be the very top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, you could use `\begin{minipage}[t]{<width>}` to top align the minipages, like @Skillmon suggested in the comments.

For the specific case of a `tcolorbox`, you should combine this with the `box align=top` option as tcolorboxes are normally bottom aligned. If you like you can fine tune the alignment to line up the first lines of text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \vskip2.2ex
    
    What do you think of this situation?

    \vspace{1cm}
    \begin{center}
    \underline{\hspace{0.75\textwidth}}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[box align=top]
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could ditch the minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.49\textwidth,nobeforeafter,box align=top,enhanced,frame hidden,interior hidden,left=0pt,right=0pt]
    What do you think of this situation?

    \vspace{1cm}
    \begin{center}
    \underline{\hspace{0.75\textwidth}}
    \end{center}
  \end{tcolorbox}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.49\textwidth,nobeforeafter,box align=top]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, `box align=top` helped a lot. I wish there were a solution that did not require fine-tuning the vspace though.

Comment: @Duncan If you don't want to fine-tune the spacing, you could ditch the minipages and use `tcolorbox`es for both columns

Comment: Great idea! Thanks for adding that to your post.

Comment: @Duncan You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the `\adjustbox` package. I also set the margins with `\showframe`.

Note: the last `\hfill` does nothing, I changed the widths of the minipages to see better. See this post [Understanding the Need for \null After \hfill in LaTeX Figure Environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707806/understanding-the-need-for-null-after-hfill-in-latex-figure-environment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe}%<-- comment in the final document
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \hfil%
  \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    What do you think of this situation?
    \vspace{1cm}
    \begin{center}
    \underline{\hspace{0.75\textwidth}}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}%
  }
  \hfil%
  \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{minipage}%
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]