Putting tikzpictures next to each other
I want the three triangles in this document to be centered and equidistant from each other. How would I do that? Sorry about the formatting, I'm new in this side of StackExchange.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \begin{document}
   % \usepackage{tkz-euclide}

    %triangle 1

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    %define points A,B,C
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,2){C}
    
    %draw triangleABC
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A,B,C)
    
    %marking right angles 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)    
    
    %marking the angles
    
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](B,A,C){$\theta$}
        
    %label the sides
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,above, ](A,C){$a$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,below, ](A,B){$\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,right](B,C){$x$}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

    %triangle 2

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    %define points A,B,C
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,2){C}
    
    %draw triangleABC
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A,B,C)
    
    %marking right angles 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)    
    
    %marking the angles
    
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](B,A,C){$\theta$}
        
    %label the sides
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,above, pos=.6, left,](A,C){$\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,below, ](A,B){$a$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,right](B,C){$x$}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

    %triangle 3

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    %define points A,B,C
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,2){C}
    
    %draw triangleABC
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A,B,C)
    
    %marking right angles 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)    
    
    %marking the angles
    
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](B,A,C){$\theta$}
        
    %label the sides
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,above, ](A,C){$x$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,below, ](A,B){$a$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,right](B,C){$\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}



Get rid of the blank lines outside the tikzpictures.  Blank lines start new paragrahs.  (TikZ has its own parser.)  You can use \hfil or \hfill instead.

As pointed out John Kormylo with \fill you can see egreg's answer to this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707806/understanding-the-need-for-null-after-hfill-in-latex-figure-environment

You can combine all three triangles in a single tikzpicture environment and place each one in a scope environment, which allows you to place it wherever you want.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \begin{document}
   % \usepackage{tkz-euclide}

    %triangle 1

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    %define points A,B,C
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,2){C}
    
    %draw triangleABC
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A,B,C)
    
    %marking right angles 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)    
    
    %marking the angles
    
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](B,A,C){$\theta$}
        
    %label the sides
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,above, ](A,C){$a$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,below, ](A,B){$\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,right](B,C){$x$}
    
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    %define points A,B,C
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,2){C}
    
    %draw triangleABC
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A,B,C)
    
    %marking right angles 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)    
    
    %marking the angles
    
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](B,A,C){$\theta$}
        
    %label the sides
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,above, pos=.6, left,](A,C){$\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,below, ](A,B){$a$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,right](B,C){$x$}
\end{scope}    
    
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
    %define points A,B,C
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,2){C}
    
    %draw triangleABC
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A,B,C)
    
    %marking right angles 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)    
    
    %marking the angles
    
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](B,A,C){$\theta$}
        
    %label the sides
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,above, ](A,C){$x$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,below, ](A,B){$a$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,right](B,C){$\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$}
\end{scope}   
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}



There are several ways to do it. Here I show you one using \hspace{\stretch{1}}.
But first, there are some problems with your code affecting typesetting:

LaTeX type-sets a blank line as a new line, like you have between adjacent tikzpicture environments
your pictures are too wide to fit into one line

So I scoped your 3 tikzpictures AND indented them out, i.e. to the left. To show this layout effect I put some blindtext above and below to recognize the page margins.
If you'd typeset:
...
\hspace{\stretch{2}} ... \hspace{\stretch{1}}
...

LaTeX would try inserting space in the ratio of 2:1 in this case ... if the line allows it; else it breaks the line.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[5]

{\parindent-2cm
 % ~~~ triangle 1 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    %define points A,B,C
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,2){C}
    
    %draw triangleABC
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A,B,C)
    
    %marking right angles 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)    
    
    %marking the angles
    
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](B,A,C){$\theta$}
        
    %label the sides
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,above, ](A,C){$a$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,below, ](A,B){$\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,right](B,C){$x$}
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
  \hspace{\stretch{1}}
 % ~~~ triangle 2 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    %define points A,B,C
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,2){C}
    
    %draw triangleABC
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A,B,C)
    
    %marking right angles 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)    
    
    %marking the angles
    
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](B,A,C){$\theta$}
        
    %label the sides
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,above, pos=.6, left,](A,C){$\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,below, ](A,B){$a$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,right](B,C){$x$}
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \hspace{\stretch{1}}
 % ~~~ triangle 3 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    %define points A,B,C
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,2){C}
    
    %draw triangleABC
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A,B,C)
    
    %marking right angles 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)    
    
    %marking the angles
    
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](B,A,C){$\theta$}
        
    %label the sides
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,above, ](A,C){$x$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,below, ](A,B){$a$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.5,right](B,C){$\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 } % ending scope of \parindent
 
 \lipsum[5]

\end{document}

